# How to suppress warning when Nunjucks template does not exist?

Tags: nunjucks

When calling `nunjucksEnvironment.render(“does-not-exist”, context)` an error is thrown.

How can I suppress that error? Alternatively, how can I check to see if a template exists before calling `.render` using whatever template loader is being used to resolve the template?

I am able to wrap the calling of the `render` method within a try/catch statement but I don’t want to eat all templating errors.

Comment: You can implement a custom loader returning an empty content if the template doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nunjucksEnvironment` has [`getTemplate`](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/blob/aa9e5b9ef1262250630985aa5667819a4f8c4e4d/nunjucks/src/environment.js#L191) method, i guess you could wrap it to check that template exist.

```js
function hasTemplate(templatePath) {
  try {
    nunjucksEnvironment.getTemplate(templatePath);
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}
```